# Using the Apple keyboard on Ubuntu with the same MacOSX mappings

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keyboard, keymap

I am currently working on an Ubuntu 12.10 workstation, and as a Mac user I would like to use the [big Apple keyboard](http://www.sweetwater.com/images/items/1800/AppleKeyAl-xlarge.jpg) (with numeric keypad) on Ubuntu with the same key mappings that I have on MacOSX.

Specifically:

- I would like to copy/paste with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C/V</kbd>, etc.
- Switch tabs with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Close applications with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- Go to begin/end line with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A/B</kbd>
- Etc

Basically, I would like the same exact keyboard behavior and experience that I have on OSX, but on Ubuntu.